# Is it possible to get notifications / events in an After Effects HTML Panel every time a change is done to the project?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I am trying to build an After Effects HTML Panel that would display all the layers from the composition. I found ExtendScript API documentation - I know how to get the layers from AE. What I'm missing is a way to refresh my panel on changes to the composition.

Does After Effect feature an event system? If yes, could you provide a link to the docs in your answer (can't find anything on Google, but I guess there must be a way to sync the panels to AE without user intervention).